# LWC html table apex call it imperatively data immutable

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am working on a simple app to retrieve field permissions and then trying to update back. However, if I change the data using UI, I don't see the changed data in the log. I see this blog by @sfdcfox mentioned that wired data is immutable and we have to clone it. In my case, it is not wired data and I am calling apex method using a button, but still, I cloned the data and try to use it.

The data is reading properly, but no updates are manipulating the data.

**HTML table:**

```
<tbody>                
                                 <template if:true={permissionData}>  
                                        <template for:each={permissionData} for:item="perm"> 
                                            <tr key={perm.key}> 
                                                <td key={perm.key}>  
                                                    <lightning-input type="checkbox" ></lightning-input>                                                                          
                                                </td>                   
                                                <td key={perm.key}>  
                                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Name"> {perm.key}  </div>                      
                                                </td>                        
                                                <template for:each={perm.value} for:item="permActions">
                                                    <td key={permActions.Id}> 
                                                        {permActions.profilename}
                                                        <lightning-input type="checkbox" label="Read" checked={permActions.readvalue} onchange={statusChanged}></lightning-input>   
                                                        <lightning-input type="checkbox" label="Edit" checked={permActions.editvalue} onchange={statusChanged}></lightning-input> 
                                                    </td>
                                                </template>
                                            </tr>
                                          </template>
                                  </template>
                            </tbody>
```

**JS:**

```
 fetchPermissions({ sObjectName: 'Account', fieldList: JSON.stringify(this.selectedOptionsList)})
            .then(data => {
                this.permissionData =[];                
                let mutableData = Object.assign({},data);               

                for(let key in mutableData) {
                    // Preventing unexcepted data
                    if (mutableData.hasOwnProperty(key)) { // Filtering the data in the loop
                        this.permissionData.push({value:mutableData[key], key:key});
                    }
                }


                let recordsCount = this.permissionData.length;  
                this.totalrecords = recordsCount;  
                    if (recordsCount !== 0 && !isNaN(recordsCount)) {  
                    this.totalpages = Math.ceil(recordsCount / this.pagesize)
                    }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.error = error;
            });
```

Screenshot:
[image]

**Error**:
If you see the screenshot, after loading the data I unchecked the Read and Write input checkbox, however in the console it is still showing both "true".

Note: The reason, I was not able to use data table is that the data is complex which I was not able not to fit into the data table. For example, having two checkboxes in the same cell.

**handle update:**

```
 handleUpdate(){
        window.console.log('Updated List: '+JSON.stringify(this.permissionData));
    }
```

Comment: how are you handling statusChanged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LWC is not 2-way binding and so `value` or `checked` mentioned in `lightning-input` will not get automatically updated.

You need to update the intended value manually in `onchange` method handler.

```
<lightning-input type="checkbox" label="Read" checked={permActions.readvalue} onchange={statusChanged}>
  </lightning-input>
```

For this, you need below:

```
statusChanged(event) {
    this.permActions.readvalue = event.target.checked;
}
```

and then when you check `permActions`, it will be updated.

**NOTE:** The `value` or `checked` attribute you use in `lightning-input` can be used only for setting default value.

**-----added------**

You can have `data-` attributes inside iteration to update correct object. Example:

```
<lightning-input type="checkbox" label="Read" checked={permActions.readvalue} 
                   data-mid="some_reference"
                   onchange={statusChanged}>
</lightning-input>
```

and in JS:

```
statusChanged(event) {
    if (event.target.dataset.mid === 'some_reference') this.permActions.readvalue = event.target.checked;
}
```

You can pass record Id or any other identifiable property in `data-` attribute.

Comment: I understand that, however, how do we update the value to the specific row, we need row details with index to match the record? and also what if I do mass update for all the rows?

Comment: added in answer

Answer (score 0):

I've found the best way to handle creating a list dynamically is to have a separate component representing the row, enabling you to reference the row in the onchange handlers.

Comment: maybe, I would do this so that I can get the row details and update that row with the changed values?